Concatenate PDFs Without Loading Them All Into Memory
I want to merge many existing PDFs without loading them all into memory at the same time. How do I do this (in Python) without calling external subprocesses?

For example, pypdf
from pypdf import PdfWriter

files = 100 * [ './testfile.pdf' ]

try:
    merger = PdfWriter()

    for f in files:
        merger.append(f)

    merger.write('output.pdf')

finally:
    merger.close()

consumes on average a whopping 7.53 MB of RAM per file (a single page test pdf, evaluating using Gnu time /usr/bin/time -f "%M") even though that single file is just 3.76 MB.
Using PyMuPDF
import fitz

merger = fitz.open()

for pdf in files:
    with fitz.open(pdf) as file:
        merger.insert_pdf(file)

merger.save("output.pdf")

this is already down to 3.76 MB / file - so no relevant overhead but still completely in memory.
Using pdftk this is just 1.22 MB / file for the same task.* So it is possible.
(ImageMagick's convert is similar [7.79 MB / file] to pypdf.)

* /usr/bin/time -f "%M" pdftk $(for i in {1..100};do echo 'testfile.pdf';done) cat output output.pdf

P.S. Using ghostscript, the overhead is nearly zero (0.08 MB / file).
/usr/bin/time -f "%M" gs -dNOPAUSE \
        -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=output.pdf \
        -dBATCH -dSAFE \
        $(for i in {1..100};do echo 'testfile.pdf';done)

So,
import subprocess

command = ['gs', '-dNOPAUSE', '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', '-sOUTPUTFILE={}'.format('output.pdf'), '-dBATCH'] + files

subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True)

answers the first part of the question but still relies on "external" subprocesses.
